# Increment counter continuously on mouse click in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling, dom-events

I am trying to implement counter in React.js which increments the value continuously on click but I am not getting the appropriate result, code works fine in plain html/js.

https://codesandbox.io/s/autumn-wood-fhsjx?file=/src/App.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(0);

  const continuosIncerment = () => {
    console.log(`Setting ${value}`);

    setValue(value + 1);

    timer = setTimeout(function() {
      continuosIncerment();
    }, 1000);
  };

  function timeoutClear() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button
        onMouseLeave={timeoutClear}
        onMouseUp={timeoutClear}
        onMouseDown={continuosIncerment}
      >
        Increment
      </button>
      <div>Value = {value} </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `setInterval`, `useRef` and callback approach to update state to solve your issue.

[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/button-timer-solution-fix-d7nrv?file=/src/App.js:73-595)

**Code snippet**

```js
export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(0);
  const timer = useRef(null);
  const increment = () => {
    timer.current = setInterval(() => setValue(prev => prev + 1), 500);
  };

  function timeoutClear() {
    clearInterval(timer.current);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button
        onMouseLeave={timeoutClear}
        onMouseUp={timeoutClear}
        onMouseDown={increment}
      >
        Increment
      </button>
      <div>Value = {value} </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the code for a timer that I used on my app, maybe it can help you.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./clock.css";

function Clock() {
  const [isRunning, setIsRunning] = useState(false);
  const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(0);
  const [minutes, setMinutes] = useState(0);
  const [hours, setHours] = useState(0);

  const toggleOn = () => {
    setIsRunning(!isRunning);
  };

  const reset = () => {
    setMinutes(0);
    setSeconds(0);
    setIsRunning(false);
    setHours(0);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    let interval = null;
    if (isRunning) {
      interval = setInterval(() => {
        setSeconds((seconds) => seconds + 1);
      }, 1000);
      if (seconds > 60) {
        setMinutes((minutes) => minutes + 1);
        setSeconds(0);
      }
      if (minutes > 60) {
        setHours((hours) => {
          return hours + 1;
        });
        setMinutes(0);
      }
    } else if (!isRunning && seconds !== 0) {
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [isRunning, seconds]);

  const formatedTime = () => {
    let formatedSeconds = seconds < 10 ? `0${seconds}` : seconds;
    let formatedMinutes = () => {
      if (hours >= 1) {
        if (minutes < 10) {
          return `0${minutes}`;
        } else return minutes;
      } else if (hours < 1) {
        return minutes;
      }
    };
    let formatedHours = hours < 1 ? " " : `${hours}:`;
    let formatedTime = `${formatedHours}${formatedMinutes()}:${formatedSeconds}`;
    return formatedTime;
  };

  return (
    <div className="clock">
      <h1>{formatedTime()}</h1>
      <div>
        <button className="btn btn-primary m-1" onClick={toggleOn}>
          {isRunning ? "Pause" : "Start"}
        </button>
        <button className="btn btn-primary m-1" onClick={reset}>
          Reset
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Clock;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved continous counter without using useEffect and useRef. Simple solution check it.

`import { useState } from "react"

```
function App() {
    let [count,setCount] = useState(0);

    let [timerId,setTimerId] = useState("")

    let start=()=>{
        let id = setInterval(increment,1000)
        setTimerId(id)
    }

    let increment=()=>{
        setCount(count=>count+1)
    }

    let stop=()=>{
        clearInterval(timerId)
    }
    return (
        <>
            <h1>Counter : {count}</h1>
            <button onClick={start}>Start</button>
            <button onClick={stop}>Stop</button>
        </>
    )
}

export default App`
```

Comment: sandbox Link : https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/fervent-kilby-6l63w4?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A11%2C22